# Detect video recording start

Tags: android, video-capture

In my program I'm recording audio with a microphone. And now I need to know when the user turns on a video record to release the microphone. How can I detect it. Is there any events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And now I need to know when the user turns on a video record to release the microphone.

No, the user needs to know to shut down your app before trying to record a video.

> How can I detect it. Is there any events?

You can try to use the audio focus stuff in AudioManager, though that was designed with playback in mind IIRC.

Beyond that, you have no way of knowing if anything is attempting to record video.

Comment: thats mean if we want to record a video for 30 seconds then we can not open camera app for 30 seconds or record videos then come back to own activity? Ok then do we have to implement our own video recorder through camera ?

Comment: @MuhammadAdil: If you are using `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`, there is an `EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT` (or something like that) you can include in the `Intent` to request a certain duration. The camera app does not have to honor that extra, though. If you need absolute control, such as an absolute time limit, you need to implement your own video recorder.

Comment: Man Thank you so much, I am feeling sorry for myself, Why I have missed that part in documentation ..  MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT - Set this value to limit the length, in seconds, of the video being captured. .....